# How to put labels between columns in a bar plot in R?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner with R and looking for help with plotting.

I would like to make a distribution plot in R that looks like a histogram of continuous data bucketed into columns with x-axis labels between each column to denote the range captured in each column.

Instead of continuous data though, I only have the bucketed counts. I can create a plot with barplot, however I can't find a way to label BETWEEN the columns to denote the range captured in each bar.

I've tried barplot but cannot get the labels to fall between columns instead of being treated as column labels and falling directly beneath each column.

```
dat$freq = c(5,15,20,10)
dat$mid = c(-1.5,-.5,.5,1.5) #midpoint in each bucketed range
dat$perc = dat$freq/sum(dat$freq)
barplot(dat$perc, names.arg = dat$mid)
```

Each column is labeled with the midpoint. I would instead like the labels to be -2,-1,0,1,2 BETWEEN the columns.

Thank you!

edit: dput(dat) outputs:

```
list(freq = c(5, 15, 20, 10), mid = c(-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5),  perc =
c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2))
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `dput(df)` into your question?

Comment: @fugu added - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
df <- data.frame(freq = c(5, 15, 20, 10), mid = c(-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5), perc = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4, 0.2))
```

I'm using the awesome and highly customisable library [ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org) to plot this, which renders the plot as I think you want it. You can install this with `install.packages('ggplot2')`:

```
# install.packages('ggplot2')
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df)
p <- p + geom_bar(aes(mid, perc), stat='identity')
p
```

[image]